# Algebra and Complexity Classes

Tags: complexity-theory, algebra

Assume functions f1 and f2 compute the same result by processing the same argument. We find that T_f1 = 120 N and T_f2 = 10 N log(2)N. Solve for what size these functions take the same amount of time

When starting to solve this I can call log(2)N ln(N) right? I believe that is a rule regarding complexity classes

Comment: This seems off-topic as it's purely a math question. It might belong at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sorry, this thought occurred to me, but I am more unsure about the assumptions about the logarithm, that should have been my question in the first place I will revise now

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math rather than programming.  math.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

**No, this question is not about complexity classes**. You are given not the asymptotic complexity of the funcitons, but concrete measure of their time complexity.

**No, you cannot replace `log(2)N` with `ln N` here**. That is because you are given actual number of operations, not a number with some constant multiplier.

```
ln N = ln 2 * log(2) N. This is approximately 0.69 log(2) N
```

If you replace one with the other you will get a wrong answer. In order to answer the question you have to solve the equation

```
120 N = 10 N log(2)N
```

> The answer is N = pow(2,12) = 4096